# Error getting tag from DatePickerFragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, datepicker, tags

I'm creating an app with two DatePicker to set a start and an end dates. As the DatePicker are called from DialogFragments, I set two tags to differentiate the results in the main activity:

```
 @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.sel_start_date:
                DialogFragment startDatePicker = new DatePickerFragment();
                startDatePicker.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), START_DATE_PICKER_TAG);
                break;
           case R.id.sel_end_date:
                DialogFragment endDatePicker = new DatePickerFragment();
                endDatePicker.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), END_DATE_PICKER_TAG);
                break;
```

The DatePickerFragment class:

```
public class DatePickerFragment extends DialogFragment {
    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        int year = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        int month = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        int day = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), (DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener) getActivity(), year, month, day );
    }
```

and this is how I get the result in the main activity

```
  @Override
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int dayOfMonth) {
        if (view.getTag().equals(START_DATE_PICKER_TAG)) {
            calendarStartDate.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
            calendarStartDate.set(Calendar.MONTH, month);
            calendarStartDate.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dayOfMonth);
            start_date_btn.setText(dayOfMonth + "/" + (month + 1) + "/" + year);
        } else {
            calendarEndDate.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
            calendarEndDate.set(Calendar.MONTH, month);
            calendarEndDate.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dayOfMonth);
            end_date_btn.setText(dayOfMonth + "/" + (month + 1) + "/" + year);
        }
    }
```

However, I get a nullPointerException doing view.getTag(). How can I solve this, or how else can I diferentiate the results?

Aclaration: DatePickerDialog is a native class, not one which I created, so I can't edit their methods`

TimePickerFragment:

```
public class TimePickerFragment extends DialogFragment {
    private static final String ARGS_TAG = "ARGS_TAG";

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        int hour = calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
        int minute = calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

        final String tag = getArguments().getString(ARGS_TAG);
        return new TimePickerDialog(getActivity(), (TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener) getActivity(), hour, minute, android.text.format.DateFormat.is24HourFormat(getActivity())) {
                @Override
                protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                }
            };
    }

    public static TimePickerFragment newInstance(String tag){
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString(ARGS_TAG, tag);
        TimePickerFragment fragment = new TimePickerFragment();
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution:** Define two interface to forward data from fragments to activity.

**Step 1**. Define `OnDateSetListener` interface to communicate between `MainActivity` and `DatePickerFragment`.

```
public interface OnDateSetListener {
    void onDateSet(String tag, DatePicker view, int year, int month, int dayOfMonth);
}
```

**Step 2**. Define `OnTimeSetListener` interface to communicate between `MainActivity` and `TimePickerFragment`.

```
public interface OnTimeSetListener {
    void onTimeSet(String tag, TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute);
}
```

**Step 3**. Let `MainActivity` implements both of interfaces.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnDateSetListener, OnTimeSetListener {

    // Your code her
    ...

    @Override
    public void onDateSet(String tag, DatePicker view, int year, int month, int dayOfMonth) {
        // Process code with tag here
    }

    @Override
    public void onTimeSet(String tag, TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
        // Process code with tag here.
    }
}
```

**Step 4**. Change code in `DatePickerFragment`

```
public class DatePickerFragment extends DialogFragment implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {
    private static final String ARGUMENT_TAG = "ARGUMENT_TAG";

    public static DatePickerFragment newInstance(String tag) {
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString(ARGUMENT_TAG, tag);
        DatePickerFragment fragment = new DatePickerFragment();
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        int year = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        int month = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        int day = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        return new DatePickerDialog(requireActivity(), this, year, month, day);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int dayOfMonth) {
        final String tag = getArguments().getString(ARGUMENT_TAG);
        OnDateSetListener listener = (OnDateSetListener) requireActivity();
        listener.onDateSet(tag, view, year, month, dayOfMonth);
    }
}
```

**Step 5**. Change code in `TimePickerFragment`.

```
public class TimePickerFragment extends DialogFragment implements TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener {
    private static final String ARGS_TAG = "ARGS_TAG";

    public static TimePickerFragment newInstance(String tag) {
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString(ARGS_TAG, tag);
        TimePickerFragment fragment = new TimePickerFragment();
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        int hour = calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
        int minute = calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
        return new TimePickerDialog(requireActivity(), this, hour, minute, DateFormat.is24HourFormat(getActivity()));
    }


    @Override
    public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
        final String tag = getArguments().getString(ARGS_TAG);
        OnTimeSetListener listener = (OnTimeSetListener) requireActivity();
        listener.onTimeSet(tag, view, hourOfDay, minute);
    }
}
```

Comment: This worked great, thanks!! Now I'm trying yo do the same with a time picker, but as in TimePickerDialog isn't a `getTimePicker()` method I'm a bit stucked there

Answer (score 0):

As I see, you've set the tag to the **Fragment**, but what you're trying to get is the tag of the **View**. They are not the same thing, as a view's tag is an object, while a fragment's tag is a string.

Comment: I see. And how could I get the Fragment tag then?

Comment: Either send the tag of the Fragment along with **onDateSet**, or set the tag of the View in onViewCreated.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see your view in onDateSet is a DatePicker, and you set your tag on the fragment containing the DatePicker, which is the DatePickerDialog.

So to get your tag you should try something like:

```
@Override
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int dayOfMonth) {
        if (view.getParent() != null && view.getParent().getTag().equals(START_DATE_PICKER_TAG)) {
            calendarStartDate.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
            calendarStartDate.set(Calendar.MONTH, month);
            calendarStartDate.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dayOfMonth);
            start_date_btn.setText(dayOfMonth + "/" + (month + 1) + "/" + year);
        } else {
            calendarEndDate.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
            calendarEndDate.set(Calendar.MONTH, month);
            calendarEndDate.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dayOfMonth);
            end_date_btn.setText(dayOfMonth + "/" + (month + 1) + "/" + year);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Just tried this, and while the fragment has a getTag method, in view.getParent().getTag() the method can't be resolved